# How to set scale type for stub image in Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, imageview, progress-bar, universal-image-loader

I have progressbar drawable with animation and set it in UniversalImageLoader configuration.The problem is when I have scale type in my ImageView the progress stub image is scaling too.

```
R.drawable.dancing_ellipsis:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:duration="33" android:drawable="@drawable/ellipsis_20" />
  <item android:duration="33" android:drawable="@drawable/ellipsis_21" />
  <item android:duration="33" android:drawable="@drawable/ellipsis_22" />
  <item android:duration="33" android:drawable="@drawable/ellipsis_23" />
  <item android:duration="500" android:drawable="@drawable/ellipsis_39" />
</animation-list>
```

---

```
final DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .postProcessor(null)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(150))     
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.image_catalog_error)    
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.dancing_ellipsis)
```

---

```
    ...
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView);
```

---

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Comment: Could you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

This result since stub image and network image use same `ImageView`, and `scaleType` is an attribute for `ImageView` apply to image source.

If you want to use different `scaleType`, there are two ways, one way is to use two `ImageView`, the other way is to update `scaleType`.

Way1:

```
public class PreImageLoadingListener implements ImageLoadingListener {
    ImageView preImage

    public PreImageLoadingListener(ImageView preImage) {
        this.preImage = preImage;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        preImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        preImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

    }
}
```

Way2:

```
public class PreImageLoadingListener implements ImageLoadingListener {
    ImageView.ScaleType preScaleType;
    ImageView.ScaleType scaleType;

    public PreImageLoadingListener(ImageView.ScaleType preScaleType, ImageView.ScaleType scaleType) {
        this.preScaleType = preScaleType;
        this.scaleType = scaleType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        imageView.setScaleType(preScaleType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        imageView.setScaleType(scaleType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

    }
}
```